# I am not able to export my DB with wamp server 2.0 and win 7

Tags: mysql, windows-7, phpmyadmin, wampserver

When I am trying to export my DB as a .sql file, downloaded popup showing export.php file. Wamp version and OS : wamp 2.0 and win 7.

But Same version wamp server perfectly working with XP.

Is it OS based issue? Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: Did you try _typing in_ the desired filename the popup dialog?

Comment: Yes, Always using new files name in the "File name template" field.

Comment: Are phpMyAdmin versions same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export your database by using command line interface. On windows, run cmd.exe, then type

```
mysqldump -u USER -p DATABASE > filename.sql
```

Remember to replace USER by your username and DATABASE by your database name, you'll be promted to enter your password.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, unfortunately above command not working for me.  Used command like this mysqldump -u root -p royalpro royalnew.sql
Error msg - 'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Answer (score -1):

left click on wampserver icon >> phpmyadmin >> on the left panel, click on the database that you wish to export >> export >> select the format you want it in (default sql) >> GO !!!